# Cannot find device path for USB Bluetooth adapter

Tags: 14.04, usb, xubuntu, bluetooth, paths

I am trying to use a Bluetooth adapter (known as `Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)` in lsusb, see further below) under Xubuntu 14.04, but my system never recognizes it.

I read that using hid2hci could help, but for that, I need to find the exact device path (which should be found somewhere within /sys/ apparently). How do I find that device's path?

lsusb output:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4503 Broadcom Corp. Mouse (Boot Interface Subclass)
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0a5c:4502 Broadcom Corp. Keyboard (Boot Interface Subclass)
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c51b Logitech, Inc. V220 Cordless Optical Mouse for Notebooks
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

lspci output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset DRAM Controller (rev 03)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 3 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 210] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR5212/AR5213 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

lsmod output:

```
fred@fred-xubuntu:~$ lsmod | grep bt
btusb                  32412  0 
bluetooth             395423  11 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
fred@fred-xubuntu:~$ lsmod | grep bluetooth
bluetooth             395423  11 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
```

Some attempts at using hid2hci:

```
fred@fred-xubuntu:~$ /lib/udev/hid2hci --method=logitech-hid --devpath=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb4/4-2/4-2.1/4-2.1:1.0
error: could not find hiddev device node
fred@fred-xubuntu:~$ /lib/udev/hid2hci --method=logitech-hid --devpath=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb4/4-2/4-2.2/4-2.2:1.0
error: could not find hiddev device node
```

By the way, I've read there's a way to make bluetooth adapters work by doing some tweaking on Windows, but I'd prefer to know if there's a way to rely only on Linux to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while installing a dual boot system with Win7x64 and Ubuntu 14.04. I have the same Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub as you do.

I booted Windows and turned on the bluetooth adapter. After I booted Ubuntu and I saw the bluetooth.

I can't explain why yet.

Comment: The question specifically states (at the end) that he isn't interested in solutions involving Windows.